# Goland shows some strange characters in console

Tags: go, goland, go-gin

Sorry I really don't know how to describe my question.I'm new to study `Gin`:

When I run "go build xxxx" in Goland, like:

[image]

the console shows some unusual words:

[image]

I think the cause is that:`Gin` wants to show us some colorful words but the console couldn't parse them well so it show us the origin code of those color text.

How to make sure the console gives the parsed words?

Comment: On which OS are you?

Comment: @artspb I am working on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug, you can read more about it [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-238965) as well as vote for the issue to get notified of progress. To work around the problem, please do the following.

1. Open *Help | Find Action...*
2. Type *Registry* and hit *Enter*.
3. Find `go.run.processes.with.pty` and disable it.